# How to apply css property to a child element using JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom

Is there a way to select a component with multiple children, point to one of them and apply css properties or some class?

Let's say I have this div:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div>Child 1</div>
   <div>Child 2</div>
   <div>Child 3</div>
</div>
```

I would like to apply a css property to the second div.

I've tried this:

```
$('.parent')[0].children[1].css('display', 'block')
```

But I am getting this error: `Cannot read property 'children' of undefined`

What I don't understant is that if I log `$('.parent')[0].children[1]` into the console I get the child div, so, I supposed that would be the way, but it seems that I am wrong.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: remove `[0]` =))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use an array index on a jQuery object, it returns a DOM element, not a jQuery object, so you can't use jQuery methods on it. Use `.eq()` to keep it as jQuery objects.

```js
$('.parent').eq(0).children().eq(1).css('display', 'block');
```

```css
.parent div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
   <div>Child 1</div>
   <div>Child 2</div>
   <div>Child 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find` method on parent to select all child `div` elements and then use `eq` method to select specific child by index.

You can also do that with selector such as `$('.parent > div:eq(1)')`

```js
$('.parent').find('div').eq(1).css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div>Child 1</div>
  <div>Child 2</div>
  <div>Child 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code should work.

```js
$(".container div").css("background-color", "red");
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Just give the second div an ID and instead of using `div` use `#second-div-id`.